# outlook 365 - restore from backup file and only IMAP synchronize recent emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I have a web email account with over 100,000 emails, and about 30 folders dating back 18 years.
I created an Outlook .pst backup of the account from my old computer which was running Outlook 2010, and restored it onto my new computer running Outlook 365, and set up the correct IMAP server address and ports.

Office 365 has been showing a "Synchronizing Inbox" message for the last half hour, and I don't see any new messages in my inbox from the last few days (the time since the backup was created).

1. How long will it take to fully synchronize with the IMAP servers? Is there a way to see detailed progress?
2. Is there some way to tell Outlook 365 to only synchronize messages from the last week and forward? It is unnecessary to synchronize the last 18 years of emails, since they were already restored from the backup file

Comment: I have a web email account with over 100,000 emails, ....    Office 365 has been showing a "Synchronizing" for the last half hour,  .....   Is there, was there, an OST file with all these older emails?  Archiving was also create an archive PST or OST file

Comment: I created .pst files which I transferred over to the new computer. I don't see any .ost files. But I still have access to the old computer, in case I need to generate them or find them (it's a Windows 7 machine)

Comment: “How long will it take to fully synchronize with the IMAP servers? Is there a way to see detailed progress?” - If you actually have 100,000 emails on the server you’re likely looking at a good amount of time. The original computer should have an .OST file, which is a cache, of the emails on the server.

Comment: Is it going to be on the order of hours, days, weeks, or more to sync? I can only find .pst files on the old computer. Perhaps it's because it was an Outlook 2010 installation. I found documentation which says "In Outlook 2013 and earlier versions, IMAP accounts also used an Outlook Data File (.pst)." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-222eaf92-a995-45d9-bde2-f331f60e2790

Comment: Just follow the fixes provided in this article: https://solutionbay.com/solutions/how-to-fix-slow-imap-syncing-issues-in-outlook If any of the methods do not work to remove the problem, then you need to remove and add the IMAP account again with the Outlook.

Besides, it is difficult to calculate the time required for synchronization, after all, due to many factors, and it is not possible to import only a part of the PST.